Generic return type that extends a base type
I'm strugling to understand a TS2322 error with the following code :
type BaseResponse = {
    a : number;
}

type ExtendedResponse = BaseResponse & {
    b: string;
}

type Fn = <T extends BaseResponse>() => T


type A = {
    fn : Fn;
}

const arr : A[] = [{
    fn : () => { // Error in this case
        return {
            a: 4
        }
    } 
}, 
{
    fn: () => { // Error in that case too
        return {
            a: 5,
            b: 'hello'
        }
    }
}]

Here, even with a response signature of BaseResponse, the compiler tells me :  '{ a: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'BaseResponse'. What does it mean?

In a generic function the caller specifies the generic type argument, not the implementer.  The type <T extends BaseResponse>()=>T means "a caller can chose any subtype of BaseResponse they like, call me with no argument, and I'll return that type for them." Like a caller is free to call fn<{a: number, z: string}>().z.toUpperCase(). Essentially impossible. That's why you're getting an error; the values {a: 4} and {a: 5, b: 'hello'} might not be what the caller wants. You're using generics wrong. So how do we go from here? What are you trying to do?
